# How to properly combine image using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, image-stitching

I have satellite images like this:

- Images are all squares and have the size of 1024px.
- One images corresponds to 1600m of square land.
- Each adjacent image has overlaps of 1%.

So if I want to combine those images, I need to remove the overlapping area (grey) and leave the center area (green). The size of the remain are are 1584m (1600*99%) and 1013.76px.

The schematic showing the overlaps:
[image: The schematic showing the overlaps]

I don't need to consider advanced image stitching problems.

Suppose I have 10 satellite images, and I want to combine these horizontally.

Ideally, the combined image should be 15840m and 10137.6px. But if I need to chop the image first, so a single image become 1013px (should be 1013.76), the error is 0.76px. After combining 10 images like this, the combined image is 10130px, the error becomes 7.6px, which is a lot.

What can I do to get rid of this error?

The schematic of concatenating images:
[image: The schematic of concatenating images]

Code would be somthing like this:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

imgs = [np.zeros((1024, 1024, 3), dtype=np.uint8) for _ in range(10)] # satellite images

# (1024, 1024, 3)
print(imgs[0].shape)

for i in range(len(imgs)):
    # should be from 5.12 to 1018.88
    # but need to convert to interger
    p_start = int(1024 * 0.005)
    p_end = int(1024 - 1024 * 0.005)
    imgs[i] = imgs[i][p_start:p_end, p_start:p_end]

# (1013, 1013, 3)
print(imgs[0].shape)

img_conbine = cv2.hconcat(imgs)

# (1013, 10130, 3)
print(img_conbine.shape)
```

Comment: the only real solution is to allocate slightly larger or slightly smaller buffers and interpolate the pixel values (could be as simple as weighted averaging) of the noninteger pixel values. If you can post 5 of the pictures, I will be able to post a working code example

Comment: to avoid too much interpolation, you can relax the constraints and if there are less than let's say 0.1 pixels (this value can obviously be tuned) coming from the neighbors, only interpolate the first row/column of the image and directly copy the rest. The first approach of interpolating everything can make the entire image look a bit more blurry but the second approach leaves a blurred row/column here and there. The decision really depends on the final product and subjective preferences.

Comment: You can also do things like applying a sharpen effect on the blurred lines etc, but there is always some form of averaging/filtering involved when you're dealing with non-grid aligned data.

Comment: I think error within 1px is acceptable, but in my case multiple small error can add up, which causes error more than 1px.

Comment: I don't think you understood my point regarding sub pixel interpolation. Like I mentioned, please provide a few of the images that you want to be stiched together and I'll give you a working example. If you can't provide images I have to go based off of test patterns which is not ideal

Comment: are you aware that if you make the images 1014 px, your error will only be 1 - 0.76 = 0.24 px, which is way better.

Comment: "the only real solution" is a proper stitching pipeline with proper blending and of course resampling.